# WiX: Heat causes ICE69 warning for files with the same names

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry, heat

I am developing an installer based on WiX for an WPF application. The amount of files is huge and constantly changes, thus I use `heat` utility for generating components.

```
& "$env:WIX\bin\heat.exe" dir $sourceDir -ag -dr INSTALLDIR -srd -sfrag -suid -cg ProductComponents -out Components.wxs
```

There are many have that have the same names but stored in different forlders. During the build `light` utility prints one the following messages

```
warning LGHT1076 : ICE69: Mismatched component reference. Entry 'regCA7432986A287E1C45911B23DB39A11B' of the Registry table belongs to component 'AutoMapper.dll_1'. However, the formatted string in column 'Value' references file 'AutoMapper.dll' which belongs to component 'AutoMapper.dll'. Components are in the same feature.
```

In the generated files there are such records as

```
<Component Id="AutoMapper.dll_1" Guid="*">
...
<File Id="AutoMapper.dll_1" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Plugins\PluginName\AutoMapper.dll" />
<ProgId Id="Record" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00ACB8EF-737F-3327-B129-C59300C5D5ED}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00ACB8EF-737F-3327-B129-C59300C5D5ED}\InprocServer32\6.1.1.0" Name="Class" Value="AutoMapper.Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00ACB8EF-737F-3327-B129-C59300C5D5ED}\InprocServer32\6.1.1.0" Name="Assembly" Value="AutoMapper, Version=6.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00ACB8EF-737F-3327-B129-C59300C5D5ED}\InprocServer32\6.1.1.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00ACB8EF-737F-3327-B129-C59300C5D5ED}\InprocServer32\6.1.1.0" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#AutoMapper.dll]" Type="string" Action="write" />
...
```

As you can see, the last line of code `[#AutoMapper.dll]` instead of `[#AutoMapper.dll_1]` and this behavior is the same for the rest of files that have same names. What can I do to prevent this behavior and generate normal registry records?

By the way is this a real problem or I can ignore that?

Comment: As long as the file is exactly the same in both locations it is safe to ignore ICE69 as long as you can't have a situation where they are in different features and could potentially install the one with references to the other while not installing the feature the other one is included in.

Comment: You can't generate static registry values because [#AutoMapper.dll] value is dependant on where the dll is installed which is a runtime value when you actually install the product.

Answer (score 0):

I recall encountering this with `-suid` as well, can you drop that argument without impacting your use case? If you need to reference the file ID somewhere with an expected value, you can always use a small transform to assist.

Comment: Well, removing `-suid` doesn't solve the issue. A huge blanket of warnings is still printed during build